# Programming/web development dictionary with API?

Tags: api

http://www.webopedia.com/ is what I'm looking for, but it doesn't offer an API. Are there similar services which offer APIs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DuckDuckGo has an open API which is quite flexible: take a look at https://duckduckgo.com/api. Using their "define" syntax, it's possible to get back word definitions. For example,

```
http://api.duckduckgo.com/?q=define+ostensibly&format=json&pretty=1
```

...would get you back a definition for "ostensibly" in JSON format.

The WordNik API (http://developer.wordnik.com/) is also pretty good for word definitions.

Comment: Clicking on the above link in July 2014 results in a JSON response whose fields are all empty. Has DuckDuckGo turned off the ability to ask for word definitions through this mechanism?